# NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, jackson

My application is throwing the error below, although I have in my app the `jackson-core-asl-1.4.2` and `jackson-mapper-asl-1.4.2`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.SimpleType.<init>(SimpleType.java:32)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory._fromClass(TypeFactory.java:254)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory._fromType(TypeFactory.java:266)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory.type(TypeFactory.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView.<init>(MappingJacksonJsonView.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:126)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 48 more
.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:126)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 48 more
```

What could be the reason? It's really weird the application worked before and commited the codes to SVN then when I check-out and re-run everything I get this error...

Comment: What is the correct Jackson version for Spring 3.1.0?

Comment: It seems Spring comes with it's own repackaged version of Jackson:http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/detail?name=com.springsource.org.codehaus.jackson.mapper

Comment: @PeterKnego So I just need to remove the dependency in the POM? BTW, I think I was able to get around the issue, but using v 1.7.1 instead of 1.4.2

Comment: Usually it is easiest to explicitly add a dependency, to enforce use of specific compatible versions. I would recommend 1.7.9 over 1.7.1 (patch releases are 100% backwards compatible, but there are lots of bug fixes).

Comment: canyou please tell us which version worked for you ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This looks almost certainly to be due to incompatible versions of 'core' and 'mapper' jars. You probably have incompatible versions in use via classpath.

Answer (score 7):

The problem you are having is due to an update in Google App Engine SDK (I think 1.6.1?).

I had the same problem, so I ran TattleTale to see if there are some dependency issues. Lo and behold, there is a conflict on the `org.codehaus.*` with the following 2 libraries:

- google_sql.jar
- jackson-core-asl-1.6.3.jar

While your jackson libraries are slightly different than mine, the issue remains the same. There are 2 fixes to this issue:

- Remove google_sql.jar from war/webinf/lib directory. This will cause the SDK to fail validation checks, but if you ignore the red x's your code should run fine.
- Update your GAE SDK to 1.6.2 or above. I think they fixed the issue in later SDK's but the updates also introduced some compiler warnings so look before you leap.