# Unable to start ActiveMQ service - NoSuchMethod org.codehaus.jackson.type

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I tried upgrading ActiveMQ Classic from 5.10.1 to 5.17.6 on Windows server 2019. I downloaded and unzipped the new installation folder.
From the old install folder I copied the `conf` and `data` folders to the new installation.

At first I was getting

```
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper
```

So I downloaded this class `org.codehaus.jackson.mapper` and put it in `activemq\lib` folder and that error was gone.

However, now I'm getting this when trying to start the broker service:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.fusesource.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType.<init>(java.lang.Class)'
```

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784051/nosuchmethoderror-org-codehaus-jackson-type-javatype) that this might be caused by incompatible versions of 'core' and 'mapper' jars, but I have no idea what it means. I'm a sysadmin.

Because of this error I cannot start the broker.

Comment: I cannot start ActiveMQ service due to `NoSuchmethod` error

Comment: This question really belongs on a different site (e.g. [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)) since it's not about programming.

Comment: Disagree, issue was incorrect jar class file, as i explained in answer

Comment: For what it's worth, ActiveMQ Classic 5.10.1 was released in January 2015 and 5.17.6 was released October 2023. In the almost 9 intervening years I imagine a fair number of changes have taken place so I'm not sure it's reasonable to expect your upgrade process to work. Instead of copying the old `conf` directory to the new broker I would recommend inspecting the old configuration and creating an _equivalent_ configuration using the new configuration files.

Comment: At the end of the day this is about broker _configuration_ - even when dealing with jar files. It's not about programming.

Comment: Before i posted question, i googled it first and other people posted same question on this site, as you can see from link at the end of my question

Comment: Lots of questions that shouldn't be here slip through the cracks. That doesn't means yours should too. For what it's worth, I think the [question you cited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784051/nosuchmethoderror-org-codehaus-jackson-type-javatype) is acceptable because the person asking it is actually writing an application, not just configuring a piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, deleted `org.codehaus.jackson.mapper.jar` file from `/lib` directory
Installed [jackson-core-2.16.0.jar](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.fasterxml.jackson.core) and [jackson-mapper-asl.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjacksonmapperasljar.htm)  into `/lib` directory and ActiveMQ service is up and running

Comment: ActiveMQ Classic 5.17.6 _already_ has `jackson-core-2.15.3.jar` in the `lib` directory. Adding a different version along with another jar that was previously removed may lead to other runtime problems.

Comment: no, it was missing (at least in WIndows version) and i had to download and put it in \lib folder

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was saying. ActiveMQ Classic 5.10.1 shipped with `jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.12.jar`, but that was explicitly removed at some point - probably due to the fact that it was no longer necessary with the recommended configuration. Now you are using an old configuration and you've added that library back into the broker. The problem is that you're treating the _symptom_ and not the cause. You need to determine _why_ the old library is still needed and fix the configuration so that it isn't.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the latest version of `jackson-mapper-asl` is 1.9.13 which was released over 10 years ago at this point. It has at least one ["high severity" CVE](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-r6j9-8759-g62w) which has not yet been fixed. It appears this library is no longer maintained. I strongly recommend you do not add it to your broker deployment.